# Hibernate - Three Entities in One Table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I have a problem with setting up some hibernate annotations in my entity classes.

My question is: How can I tell Hibernate, that it should store the Address, Name and Customer information in just one table. This table should have the following columns: ID, Given, Surname, Street, HouseNumber, Zip, City, Phone, Comment. At the moment Hibernate generates for each entity a single table in the mysql database. Therefore it is necessary to define an @Id in each entity class (Customer, Name, Address). But I want to keep all the information in one table with just one @Id for the customer.

How can I solve this problem?

Below you can find an extract of the Customer, the Name and the Address entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @OneToOne
    private Name name;
    @OneToOne
    private Address address;
    private String phone;
    private String comment;
    public Customer() { }
}

@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Name {
    private String given;
    private String surname;
    public Name() { }
}

@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String houseNumber;
    private String zip;
    private String city;
    public Address() { }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only `Customer` should be annotated with `@Entity`. The other classes are not entities, but only a small part of the Customer entity. They should thus be annotated with @Embeddable.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Embedded
    private Name name;
    @Embedded
    private Address address;
    private String phone;
    private String comment;
    public Customer() { }
}

@Entity
public class Name {
    private String given;
    private String surname;
    public Name() { }
}

@Embeddable
public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String houseNumber;
    private String zip;
    private String city;
    public Address() { };
}
```